# Unserialize a string

Tags: php, deserialization

I want to print `'Shareholders123'` from this data `a:1:{i:0;s:15:"Shareholders123";}`

```
<?php foreach(unserialize($model->shareholders) as $shareholder): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><strong><?php echo $shareholder['shareholders']; ?></strong></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This just print "S".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = unserialize('a:1:{i:0;s:15:"Shareholders123";}');
foreach($arr as $str) {
    echo $str;
}
```

or just simply:

```
$arr = unserialize('a:1:{i:0;s:15:"Shareholders123";}');
echo $arr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to do

```
<?php foreach(unserialize($model->shareholders) as $shareholder): ?>
    ...
    <strong><?php echo $shareholder; ?></strong>
    ...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Because you're not dealing with an associative array, so you don't need to access the value by key. In fact, you don't even have a key named 'shareholders'.

```
unserialize('a:1:{i:0;s:15:"Shareholders123";}')
```

returns this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Shareholders123
)
```